# How to install DNN Upgrade Package 07.00.05 - I have DotNetNuke Community Edition 06.00.00 (2982) hosted on iHostASP.Net

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke, upgrade, administration

I am more of a DNN end user and not a DNN developer.

When I bought my DNN hosting package from iHostASP.Net about 2 years ago, version 6.0 was the current version for the community edition and iHostASP.net set it up for me. I did not make much use of the website until now and I am planning to relaunch my website.

I see that 7.00.05 is the latest community and if I got to the DNN website from the upgrade prompt from my DNN instance, I am taken to http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Downloads.aspx

from where all I can do is download a zip file.

How do I have this upgrade package installed? What I have on iHostASP.net is a website setup, so I don't have full access to the server itself. All I can access is the Helm Control panel for my website.

I have host access to my website, but can't see how I can have the zip file uploaded or installed in my DNN instance.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Does anyone know of any breaking changes in this upgrade from 6.0.0 to 7.0.05? I am not using any outside module other than what is supplied out of the box in a default DNN community edition.

Thank in advance.

Comment: I did find an article on iHostASP.Net support pages - https://support.ihostllc.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=41 but this one is almost five years old. Can someone confirm that DNN still upgrade still follows the same procedure: 1. Unzip and overwrite files from the unzipped location to the website's root. 2. Run upgrade by navigating to http://www.mysite.com/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Suggested upgrade path](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Suggested_Upgrade_Path.aspx) recommends upgrading first to the latest DNN 6, and then to the latest DNN 7. At the moment, this means first upgrading to 06.02.07, and then to 07.00.05.

This is just a recommendation, though. If you get upgrade errors, or the site doesn't work as expected, I would try again with the suggested upgrade path.

[DNN system requirements](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Downloads/System-Requirements.aspx) have changed substantially between versions 6 and 7. Support for Windows 2003 servers has been dropped, but I doubt IHostASP.NET has used these for a while.

Comment: The "suggested" upgrade path is no longer necessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have FTP access with IHostASP, if so, you can watch this video for how to perform an upgrade

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/244/View/Details/Upgrading-A-DotNetNuke-Site-Via-FTP.aspx

You should also check out the Wiki http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Upgrading-DotNetNuke.aspx

Be absolutely sure to back everything up first though, if you don't know how, ask your hosting provider what backup options they provide.

Comment: Your links seem to be helpful. I will have to use the caution of backing up all of my application files + database first before I try out the upgrade. Thanks for the pointers!